# Possible to do input:last-child without choosing submit?

Tags: html, css, forms

Heres a snippet of the HTML I am using, to test this:

```
<form action="#" method="post">
    <input name="username" type="text" placeholder="Username" /><br />
    <input name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" /><br />
    <input name="emailAddress" type="email" placeholder="Email Address" /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

And heres a snippet of the CSS I am using, to test this:

```
form {
    width:300px;
    overflow:auto;
    margin:20px 0 0;
    padding:0;
}
/*-Inputs-*/
form input[type=text]:focus, form input[type=password]:focus {outline:0;}

form input {
    width:calc(100% - 22px);
    margin:0;
    padding:10px;
    background:#FFF;
    border:none;
    border-left:solid 1px #CCC;
    border-right:solid 1px #CCC;
}
form input:first-child {
    border-top-left-radius:5px;
    border-top-right-radius:5px;
    border-top:solid 1px #CCC;
}
form input:last-child {
    border-bottom-left-radius:5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:5px;
    border-top:none;
    border-bottom:solid 1px #CCC;
}
```

Is it possible for the `form input:last-child` to ignore the `[type=submit]`?
So that the CSS would see `[type=email]` as the last child?

**Note: Although this won't always be the layout, there will always be a submit button within my forms, which I'd like `:last-child` to be able to ignore.**

Comment: You could always use  the nth-last-child(2) if you want the one before last

Comment: @Linial - or I could just make a class `.last-child`. But I was hoping for an automatic way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

Solution 1: Using CSS selector `not` (CSS3, so not fully supported)

https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/:not

```
form input:not([type="submit"]):last-child
```

Solution 2: Apply classes to your inputs (cross-browser solution)

HTML

```
<form action="#" method="post">
    <input class="first-input" name="username" type="text" placeholder="Username" /><br />
    <input name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" /><br />
    <input class="last-input" name="emailAddress" type="email" placeholder="Email Address" /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

CSS

```
form .first-input{ }

form .last-input{ }
```

Comment: Unfortunately this solution is barely supported at the moment, I'd like to find a solution that is widely supported.

Comment: You have 2 solutions now :) (the second one will be even more cross-browser compatible than with using `:first-child` & `:last-child` which are CSS 2

Answer (score 0):

I would go for `form input:nth-last-child(2) {...} for this. It's well supported cross browser: http://caniuse.com/css-sel3, and there are [polyfills](http://css-tricks.com/how-to-use-the-webshims-polyfill/) for older browsers.